# SPOJ SHPATH - SIGSEV Error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have been trying to solve the SHPATH problem on SPOJ which is just a direct implementation of Djikstra's algorithm.

http://www.spoj.com/problems/TSHPATH/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class Graph{
    public:
        vector< pair<int,int> > adjList[10001];
        void addEdge(int city_index, int neighbor, int dist){
            adjList[city_index].push_back(make_pair(neighbor,dist));
        }
};

struct comp{
    bool operator()(const pair<int,int>& a, const pair<int,int>& b){
        return a.second > b.second;
    }
};

int dijkstra(Graph graph, int n, int source, int dest){
    priority_queue< pair<int,int>, vector< pair<int,int> >, comp> pqi;
    map<int,int> visited;
    int curr_dist;
    vector< pair<int,int> > curr;
    //Start from the source
    pqi.push(make_pair(source,0));
    while(visited.size() < n && pqi.empty == false){
        //Check if it is already visited, If already visited, then ignore
        while(visited.find(pqi.top().first) != visited.end()){
            pqi.pop();
        }
        curr = graph.adjList[pqi.top().first];
        curr_dist = pqi.top().second;
        //Mark it as visited
        visited[pqi.top().first] = curr_dist;
        pqi.pop();
        //Visit all the neighbors
        for(int j=0; j<curr.size(); j++){
            //If not already visited, then visit it
            if(visited.find(curr[j].first) == visited.end()){
                pqi.push(make_pair(curr[j].first,curr_dist+curr[j].second));
            }
        }
    }
    return visited[dest];
}

int main() {
    int t,n,neighbors,a,b,queries;
    string city1,city2;
    string city_name;
    string emptyline;
    map<string,int> city_index;
    cin>>t;
    for(int testcase=0; testcase<t; testcase++){
        Graph graph = Graph();
        cin>>n;
        for(int city=1; city<=n; city++){
            cin>>city_name;
            city_index[city_name] = city;
            cin>>neighbors;
            for(int neighbor=0; neighbor<neighbors; neighbor++){
                cin>>a>>b;
                graph.addEdge(city,a,b);
            }
        }
        cin>>queries;
        for(int query=0; query<queries; query++){
            cin>>city1>>city2;
            cout<<dijkstra(graph,n,city_index[city1],city_index[city2])<<endl;
        }
        getline(cin,emptyline);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested it against a lot of testcases from http://spojtoolkit.com/test/SHPATH

It gives the correct answer for all the testcases. Can't seem to figure out, where the segmentation fault is occuring, because there are no array index out of bounds and no wild pointers or such.

Comment: So you have an *array* of *vector*s in `Graph`?

Comment: I think you might need to check `pqi.empty()` before call `top()` or `pop()`.

Comment: Yes, Graph is implemented through adjacency list concept. And I have used a array of vectors to implement this adjacency list.

Comment: I am aware of that, I was just wondering why you mixed `vector` with `array`! Why not `vector` of `vector`s?

Comment: Because the nodes are going to be numbered 1 to n, which is fixed. It just made sense to me. I guess you could also do it with a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `djikstra()`, this line was modified:

```
while(visited.size() < n && pqi.empty() == false)
```

Now, the solution is running fine, for all test cases.